Confusion on which branch of $\tanh^{-1}(x)$ to use for real $x>1$
$\newcommand{\ath}[1]{\operatorname{arctanh}\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}$
I need to evaluate $\ath{x}$ for real $x > 1$.

To do this, I consulted the formula for  $\ath{x}$ for real $\left\vert\,{x}\,\right\vert < 1$:
$$
\ath{x} = \frac{1}{2}\,
\ln\left(\frac{1 + x}{1 - x}\right)
$$
This is the same as
\begin{align}
& \frac{1}{2}\,
\ln\left(\color{red}{-}\,\frac{1 + x}{x - 1 }\right)
\\[2mm] = & \
\frac{{\rm i}\pi}{2} +
\ln\left(\frac{x + 1}{x - 1}\right) =
\frac{{\rm i}\pi}{2} + \ath{\frac{1}{x}}
\end{align}
However, I saw a question here that arrived at the answer
$$
-\frac{{\rm i}\pi}{2} + \ath{\frac{1}{x}}
$$
How can I know which sign ( positive or negative ) to use ?.
I don't really know any complex analysis.
I came across this dilemma while trying to evaluate an antiderivative containing $\operatorname{arctanh}$.

Is it fine if I use either so long as I stick with that branch throughout the whole calculation of the integral ?.

The answer to your last sentence is “yes”.

$-\pi$ and $\pi$ are both valid answers for $\ln(-1).$

@ThomasAndrews You mean $i\pi$ and $-i\pi$ I imagine.

Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Please fix the typo in your title.

@ThomasAndrews It depends on the branch-cut you choose.

Of course, but the usual branch cut actually excludes $-1,$ or, if it defines $\ln(-1),$ it is discontinuous there. @FelixMarin
